# KeyCDN and DO Spaces: Django {% static %} vs {{ STATIC_URL}} when STATICFILES_STORAGE is set

Tags: django, cdn, digital-ocean, static-files

I am using [digitalocean.com spaces](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/) to store static files for my Django app. I set it up successfully according to their [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-object-storage-with-django) (same settings as AWS). I now want to put a CDN in front of the static files. KeyCDN has a [document](https://www.keycdn.com/support/django-cdn-integration/) describing how to do this but suggests using `{{STATIC_URL}}` in templates rather than the `{% static %}` templatetag.

Django admin uses the `{% static %}` templatetag not `{{ STATIC_URL}}`. In some cases there is no difference, however, if you define `STATICFILES_STORAGE`, as is required to store static files in [digitalocean.com spaces](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/), the templatetag `{% static %}` ignores whatever you explicitly declare in settings.py for `STATIC_URL`.

I have:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE='storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

`S3Boto3Storage` sets the template tag `{% static %}` to point to `https://ams3.digitalocean.com/bucket_name/path/to/static/` regardless of the setting of `{{ STATIC_URL }}`.

Manually setting `STATIC_URL=` in `settings.py` as KeyCDN [suggests](https://www.keycdn.com/support/django-cdn-integration/):

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://keycdndjango-1c6b.kxcdn.com/static/'
```

has no effect on what the templatetag `{% static %}` returns.

So i cannot figure out how to make KeyCDN work with this setup.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this was the case, but I'm using Digital Ocean CDN and setting AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE to 'virtual' made the change

from

`https://ams3.digitalocean.com/bucket_name/path/to/static/`

to

`https://bucket_name.ams3.digitalocean.com/path/to/static/`